# Help needed to add text to the end of a string using the "sed" command in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

In Terminal.app, I used the `curl ftp`... command to get a directory listing of folders and files from my friend's computer and I directed the output to a file called "curlFTP.txt". Each line of this file appears like these following 3 examples…

- drwxr-xr-x   1 nobody   root     4096 Aug 02  2014 WEDDING_SINGER_4X3
- drwxr-xr-x   1 nobody   root     4096 Aug 02  2014 WEEKEND_AT_BERNIES
- drwxr-xr-x   1 nobody   root     4096 Aug 02  2014 WEIRD_SCIENCE

From each of these lines of that file, I only need to keep the directory names, which would be...

- WEDDING_SINGER_4X3
- WEEKEND_AT_BERNIES
- WEIRD_SCIENCE

Using the `cut -c 52-` command, I was able to extract only these folder names which I then directed its output to a file I named "curlFTP2.txt"

The next step I needed to do was prepend each line of the file "curlFTP2.txt" with the text...`curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk\ 1\ Movies/Movies\ 1/` and direct its output to a file named "curlFTP3.txt". Now each line of the file "curlFTP3.txt" would look like these following three examples...

```
curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/WEDDING_SINGER_4X3
curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/WEEKEND_AT_BERNIES
curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/WEIRD_SCIENCE
```

Here is the full command I used, which worked incredibly well and was extremely fast, considering there was 760 lines in the file to edit.

```
cat curlFTP.txt | cut -c 52- > curlFTP2.txt ; sed 's|^|curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk\ 1\ Movies/Movies\ 1/|g' curlFTP2.txt > curlFTP3.txt
```

*(the IP address I used in this is a substitute for the IP address I actually used)*

Here is where I'm jammed up… what I need to do is use the `sed` command with the `-e` argument so I can add an additional `sed` command to the code from above and add a "/" to the end of each line of that file because each listing is a directory.

I need each line to look like this:    `curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/WEDDING_SINGER_4X3/`
Instead of each line looking like:  `curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/WEDDING_SINGER_4X3`

I was able to figure out that using the `sed 's|^|blah|g'` command, for example, the "^" character would mean adding "blah" to the beginning of each line.

So here is my question… is there a similar character I can use, like the "^" character, that would allow me to use the `sed` command to add text to the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, it is: `$`

Comment: You do not need `cat`, `|` or `cut` You could do it in one step with, e.g.,: `sed -E -e 's|^.*[A-Za-z]{3}[ ][0-9]{2}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ]|curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/|' -e 's|$|/|' curlFTP.txt > newfile.txt `

Comment: Wow. You just gave me a lot to chew on… now I'm going to have to roll up my sleeves and start teaching myself regular expressions and study the man page sed.  Your solution is quite impressive. Add it as an answer and I will upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So here is my question… is there a similar character I can use, like
>   the "^" character, that would allow me to use the sed command to add
>   text to the end of each line?

Yes, it is: `$`

That said, looking at what is is going on, let me offer you a different over all solution where you do not need to first:

```
cat curlFTP.txt | cut -c 52- > curlFTP2.txt
```

You can process the `curlFTP.txt` *file* directly and completely with `sed`:

```
sed -E -e 's|^.*[A-Za-z]{3}[ ][0-9]{2}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ]|curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/|' -e 's|$|/|' curlFTP.txt > newfile.txt
```

You could even eliminate `> newfile.txt`by using the `-i` *option* of the `sed` *command*:

> −i *extension* 
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified
>   *extension*. If a zero-length *extension* is given, no backup will be
>   saved. It is not recommended to give a zero-length *extension* when
>   in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in
>   situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

```
sed -i'.bak' -E -e 's|^.*[A-Za-z]{3}[ ][0-9]{2}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ]|curl ftp://1.1.1.1/Disk 1 Movies/Movies 1/|' -e 's|$|/|' curlFTP.txt
```

---

Using https://regex101.com to explain the *regex* used in the `sed` *command*:

[image]

Which matches e.g.:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 nobody root 4096 Aug 02 2014
```